# Listing integers from a text file into a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm creating an app in winforms c# using vs 2013.

In the app I have a textfile to which I'm saying the time in int format using a custom format from a time select dropdown list.

I then want to display what is in that text file on a selectable listview from where I can remove it from the textfile etc. I'm almost there however at the moment when I try to add the items into the listbox they do seem to add however they do not display correctly.

For example say in my text file there is

```
22102210
19101610
17182218
10272227
```

Then that is how it should be displayed in the listview as selectable ready to be deleted.

At the moment it isn't showing correctly, it's showing up as 1.. 2.. 1..

Could someone help me out and point me in the right direction as to why this might be happening? Any help much appreciated. This is my class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chronos
{
    public partial class Interface : Form
    {
        private string[] getTimes = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\Dropbox\University\Chronos\Application\Chronos\Chronos\AdminAccount\Times.txt");
    public Interface()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Interface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateList();
    }

    private void PopulateList()
    {
        int size = getTimes.Length;
        lstTime.Items.Clear();
        GetTimes();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            lstTime.Items.Add(getTimes[i]);
        }
    }

    private void GetTimes()
    {
        string[] getTimes = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\Dropbox\University\Chronos\Application\Chronos\Chronos\AdminAccount\Times.txt");
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string time = pickerTimeStart.Value.Hour.ToString() + pickerTimeStart.Value.Minute.ToString() + pickerTimeEnd.Value.Hour.ToString() + pickerTimeEnd.Value.Minute.ToString();

        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"G:\Dropbox\University\Chronos\Application\Chronos\Chronos\AdminAccount\Times.txt", time + Environment.NewLine);

        PopulateList();

        MessageBox.Show("Time added", "Ok");





        //PopulateList();
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently written, `GetTimes` does nothing except read the file:

```
private void GetTimes()
{
    // "string[]" here overrides the outer scope
    string[] getTimes = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\Dropbox\University\Chronos\Application\Chronos\Chronos\AdminAccount\Times.txt");
}
```

If you change it to this, it becomes more useful:

```
private string[] GetTimes()
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\Dropbox\University\Chronos\Application\Chronos\Chronos\AdminAccount\Times.txt");
}
```

... and then `PopulateList` can simply become:

```
lstTime.Items.Clear(); //so you aren't getting a bunch of dupes
lstTime.Items.AddRange(GetTimes().Select(t => new ListViewItem(t)).ToArray());
```

You can also remove this line because you don't need to keep a copy of the data in the class:

```
private string[] getTimes = ...
```

Note:  If you decide to keep the data source local and not work solely against the file, much of this would change.

Comment: I've taken all your comments on board and the part where I'm not storing the string array from the file makes perfect sense. For some reason when I do the lstTime.Items.AddRange(GetTimes()) it throws an error : The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Listview.ListViewItemCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCOllection)' has some invalid arguements. I'm guessing because the method .AddRange() doesn't accept a string array?

Comment: @Jagga - It doesn't.  I assumed `ListBox`, which does.

Comment: Yeah that is working and from what it seems like what I was doing first was actually populating it correctly as well. It's just the format isn't correct. So your answer I've accepted of course however I still have the same problem where it doesn't display properly. I'm not sure how this 1 is gonna be fixed. Here's a screenshot and as you can see when I select 1 of the entrys it displays it fully, although in a very unhelpful format (no formatting done yet) http://i.imgur.com/8QOmot6.jpg